# Find the potential energy of this object when it is on the ground of the Earth

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy-conservation, potential-energy

> A mass $M=1kg$ has potential energy $U=0$ when the distance to the Earth is $\infty$. Find the potential energy of this object when It's on the ground of the Earth. (The potential energy of the object at the ground of the Earth must be negative.)

I have tried a solution but I got stuck.

The object has $r_0=\infty$ distance to the World, then it has $r=0$ distance. So that means gravity of the Earth pull the object to it's ground. In that case gravity done a work.

$$W_\text{by gravity}=\int_{r_0}^{r}\vec{F}_{g}\cdot \text d\vec{r}$$

$$W_{g}=\int_{r_0}^{r}(G\frac{M_{E}M}{r^2}\hat{r})\cdot\text dr\hat{r}$$

$$W_{g}=\int_{r_0}^{r}(G\frac{M_{E}M}{r^2})\cdot\text dr$$

$$W_{g}=(GM_{E}M)\int_{r_0}^{r}\frac{1}{r^2}dr$$

$$W_{g}=(GM_{E}M)(-\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{r_0})$$

$$W_{g}=-G\frac{M_{E}M}{r}+G\frac{M_{E}M}{r_0}$$

The term $\lim_{r_0\to \infty}(G\frac{M_{E}M}{r_0})=0$ So, the Work done by gravity is,

$$W_{g}=-G\frac{M_{E}M}{r}$$

But I don't know what can I do here.

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: Also, you have a sign error in the force

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are done. This is exactly the potential energy: The work done by the (conservative) force in moving the object from a reference point $r_0$ to the end point $r$.

Comment: This is exactly the **change in** potential energy: The **negative** work done by the (conservative) force in moving the object from a reference point r0 to the end point r.

Comment: I have researched my question and I found that my solution is correct. Thanks for the answer :)